# Detect overflowed children in second line in Wrap flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using `Wrap` widget with some buttons like the image below. "B" Button move to next line because there is now width space

How to detect when children overflows/moves to second line? because I want to show the moved buttons in `showDialog` instead when there is no space in the first line.

Code:

```dart
return Wrap(
  children: <Widget>[
    ElevatedButton(child: const Text('Foo')),
    ElevatedButton(child: const Text('Foo Bar')),
    ElevatedButton(child: const Text('Foo Bar Bas')),
    ElevatedButton(child: const Text('F')),
    ElevatedButton(child: const Text('B'))
  ],
);
```

Output:

[image]